# jubula and access to backend database

Tags: java, testing

Is it possible to test with jubula testing tool correspondence between user interface and data that is stored in database? For example I want to be sure that every field shows information is is intended to show.

If that scenario is not possible could you advice any other testing tool or workaround to do it on jubula (may be some 3rd party plugins)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access a DB from Jubula tests out of the box. However there are a few possibilities which need some work from you:

1. You may use the "Execute External Command" test step and compare values from the tests to values stored in a DB.
2. You may write an extension to Jubula. The right component would be Application and you are free to write whatever Java code is needed to access your DB.
3. You can convince the Jubula team that you have a generally usable approach to DB checks and file a feature request in [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jubula). Some source code would go great with that.

Points 1 and 2 are covered in the Jubula documentation.